# How do I add an SSH key in gitlab?

Tags: ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys

Here is what my dashboard looks like:

[image]

Not really sure where to add an SSH key. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. You need to sign in. Green button top right.
2. Click 'profile settings' on the left side menu.
3. Click SSH Keys and follow the instructions on the page.

Answer (score 26):

Go to your GitLab account: https://gitlab.com/

Click on Settings on the top right drop-down, which will appear once you select the icon(white-fox image [specific to my profile]).
[image]

Click on Settings on the top right drop-down, which will appear once you select the icon(white-fox image).

Click on SSH Keys:
[image]

Add/Paste the SSH Key.
How to generate the ssh key: Download gitbash or putty:

After downloading gitbash/putty follow the steps:

1. Open a terminal on Linux or macOS, or Git Bash / WSL on Windows.
2. Generate a new ED25519 SSH key pair:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "email@example.com"
   ```

   Or, if you want to use RSA:

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
   ```

   It will generate the key in => C:\Users\yourname.ssh directory.
3. Copy the public key and paste in the gitlab location:

   [image]

Command to run on gitbash to clone the repository:

```
ssh-agent $(ssh-add C:\Users\youname\.ssh\id_rsa; git clone git@gitlab.com:xyz/SpringBootStarter.git)
```

Comment: for copy ssh_key (mac): pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Comment: for copy ssh_key (windows) : type %userprofile%\.ssh\id_rsa.pub | clip

Answer (score 3):

Goto https://gitlab.com/profile/keys.

If you are a new user a banner will show at the top of each project page.

> You won't be able to pull or push project code via SSH until you add
>   an SSH key to your profile

However, you can dismiss this warning.

Comment: what is the meaning of this warning?

Comment: Unless you are pulling and pushing your code over https, you need a SSH key in order to work with gitlab.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open the terminal and type: ssh-keygen -t rsa
2. It will display something like this: -> Generating public/private rsa key pair.
   Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\abc/.ssh/id_rsa):
3. Copy the path: C:\Users\abc/.ssh/id_rsa -> Enter file in which to save the key (C:\Users\sonnguyen/.ssh/id_rsa): C:\Users\sonnguyen/.ssh/id_rsa -> press Enter
4. Enter a password and confirm the password
5. You will see the location of the generated SSH key open in Notepad; copy this and paste it into GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to do open terminal after that type

```
   mkdir -p ~/.ssh
   echo public_key_string >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
   chmod -R go= ~/.ssh
   chown -R shabeer:shabeer ~/.ssh
   ssh-keygen  or ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "mail@example.com"
   xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub
   ~/.ssh/gitlab_rsa.pub
```

in this time can see your key and copy it, After that Go to the Gitlab settings and chose SSH Keys, you can see there have to option add that copied key